# SAS help: How to move the contents (N, Mean, Min and Max) of AGE variable in SAS?

Tags: sas

SAS help: How to move the contents (N, Mean, Min and Max) of AGE variable? For example I want, to move the contents of AGE variable to 3 spaces;

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is not "move", it is just adding space at the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're after

```
data your_data2;
    set your_data;
    if name ~= "age" then name = "  "||strip(name);
run;
```

Comment: Instead of spaces you may also try "09"x which is a tab, depending on your destination this may be required.